# What specific value does fontSize in px actually define

Tags: html, css, font-size

I need to create a graphical element that needs to be exactly twice the height of a capitalized letter.

I have the font size defined externally with JS using 'px' and then the graphic is drawn based on this same value.

As a rule of thumb, I have been using 1.5x of the px font-size value to be the capital height. However, this is not accurate enough and changes at larger sizes.

so what exactly does font size define and is there a way to know its mathematical relation to a capitalized letter in a font?

Comment: I would suggest you to check [What does font-size really correspond to?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42026239/what-does-font-size-really-correspond-to)

Also, be sure to check [Relative Units — CSS](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp) at the end of that page.

Hope that helps!